# contradiction proof of odd function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know if i am doing this problem correctly, in regards to the factoring of 
$4k^2+2(2k)$
.

for integer n , $ n^2 +2n$ is odd, then $n$ is odd

Prove statement by contradiction:

Assume there an integer n such that $ n^2 +2n$ is odd an $n$ is even,

By definition of even $2k$,  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Substitute values:

$4k^2+2(2k)$

Comment: Conclusion? ${}{}$

Comment: which part do you feel confused?

Comment: @ZackNi what would the factored form be $4k^2+2(2k)$

Comment: $4k^2 + 2(2k) = 2(2k^2 + 2k)$. What can you conclude?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 that its even